# NextJS module resolution error with multiple paths in my path resolution

Tags: javascript, next.js, vscode-jsconfig

Hi everyone :) I was hoping I could get some fresh eyes on a problem I'm running into on my project:

I have a NextJS (12.1.4) project using absolute imports, I also have an NPM package where I directly import the source files in my project (since it's a library for shared components, internal use only). This package is called `bs-components` here.

Here is my `jsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@bscom/*": ["node_modules/@company/bs-components/*"],
      "*": ["node_modules/@company/bs-components/*", "*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I will explain the intent behind my `paths` config here:

The first entry for `@bscom/*` will allow me to import modules from my library using a shorthand.

The second entry for `*` is intended so that the module resolution goes like this:

- Look in the component library first for a module, so that absolute imports in the component library are respected.
- If module is not found in the library, then resolve using the `baseUrl` as the starting point for resolution.

Unfortunately when using this config, absolute imports within the component library fail with the following error:

```
./node_modules/@company/bs-components/styling/resets.js:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'constants/colors'
```

This happens in my NextJS `_document.js` file, so during the server render step.

There are no modules with that path in my main project which could cause a conflict.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Where is `constants/colors`?

Comment: This is in my component library - so the full path would be @company/bs-components/constants/colors

Comment: Have you tried using local path? "../constants/colors"

Comment: I know that that would work - the problem is that the component library used to work with absolute imports, and changing this would take a lot of time, I was wondering if it was possible for me to keep my absolute imports using the method outlined above.

Comment: Do you want to override your libs defaults with those in the project root?